# Upload image to a database and Display the image

Tags: php, mysql

i have a html form and i added a {input type="file" name="file"} tag to the form. when i choose an image and hit the submit, how it does submit to the database and how can i retrieve the image to a php file?

{my database name - uploadimg}

{my DB username - root}

{No DB password}

{Table name - table_image}

Answer (score 0):

You can upload the file through below code

```
if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is recomended to store uploaded images in a folder and the image names in the db.for uploading images the first you need to check is the enctype attribute in your form tag.you should specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your form tag. Without this attribute the image doesn't get uploaded and then images can be uploaded using `$_FILES['field_name']['name'],$_FILES['field_name']['tmp_name'],.....`

But still if you want to insert the image directly into the database you should use your database column datatype as `BLOB`

Answer (score 0):

```
                            $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $type =  $_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $timestamp = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');               
            $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];
            $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);
        if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
          {
          if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
            {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
            }
          else
            {
            "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

              if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
              {
             $sql = 'insert into table_image(img_name, type, size, uploadtime, status) values("'.$name.'", "'.$type.'", "'.$size.'", "'.$timestamp.'", "1")';
                 $rs = mysql_query($sql);                                       
               }     
            }
          }
        else
          {
          echo "Invalid file";
          }
        }
```

Comment: now I can upload images to the database, but how can i display the image which i uploaded in php?

Answer (score 0):

```
          $sql = 'select * from table_image';
          $rs = mysql_query($sql);
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
           {    
              echo '<img src="images/'.$row['img_name'].'">';
              }
```